# JavaScript función seAbre y aperturas

Tags: javascript

Buenas me dan el siguiente problema:

Una profesora representa a los ingresos de los estudiantes como un array de tiempos de llegada tarde, en minutos. Por ejemplo, si un estudiante llegó 10 minutos tarde, otro 5 minutos antes de hora, otro 3 minutos tarde, y otro puntual, lo representa así:
var ingresosDelLunes = [10, -5, 3, 0];

Con esta información y la cantidad de estudiantes mínimos para abrir el curso, la profesora quiere saber si la clase se abre. Suponiendo que la cantidad minima de estudiantes para que la clase se de es 2, el curso del lunes se abre, porque hubo un estudiante que llegó puntual y un estudiante que llegó temprano.

seAbre(ingresosDelLunes, 2)
true

Pero si la cantidad mínima fuera 3, la clase no se abriria:

seAbre(ingresosDelLunes, 3)
false

Escribi las siguientes funciones:

seAbre, que dice si se hace una clase dado el array de ingresos
aperturas, que toma un array con los arrays de ingresos de varios días, y la cantidad mínima de estudiante, y diga que dias se abrió y que días no. Por ejemplo:
aperturas([ingresosDelLunes, ingresosDelMartes, ingresosDelMiercoles], 2)
[true, false, false]

yo realicé lo siguiente:

```
 function seAbre (array,ingresos) {
    let contador=0;
    for (let i=0 ; i< array.length ; i++){
        if (array[i]<= 0) {
            contador++;
        }
        return contador>=ingresos;
    }
}

function aperturas (array2, ingresos2) {
    let array3=[];
    for (let i=0 ; i<array2.length ; i++) {
        array3.push( seAbre(array2[i],ingresos2));
    }
        return array3;
}
```

Y me tira "expected false to equal true", y sinceramente no veo el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El return está en el lugar equivocado:

```
function seAbre (array,ingresos) {
    let contador=0;
    for (let i=0 ; i< array.length ; i++){
        if (array[i]<= 0) {
            contador++;
        }  
    }
   return contador >= ingresos;
}
```

Comment: Que b***** jaja gracias!